# How to show avatar as a full image with Jet Engine and Elementor?

Tags: elementor, jet-engine

I'm having issues in showing any images (avatar) using the jet-engine-query builder.

I have successfully included other data taken from the database into a profile section for my website, however no matter what I try it's not permitting me to display the avatar.

I have a profile page set up using Elemento Pro and Jet Engine. Each section has the relaxant sql query items, to which they are all showing correctly.

Where the avatar section is I'm just getting the name of the file (Julie.jpg) this should show the image.

This is the format I used to connect the database.

Query builder, query type = SQL  AI Query.  Advanced AI mode.

**SQL Query**

SELECT *
FROM users

Created Jet engine listings. Drag drop over **Dynamic Field**  selected *Post/Term/User/Object*  I Open **Object Field**, and locate the **user section**, select the **avatar**.

Repeated this same process to add **user_name, and description**.

The issue is that the avatar only outputs the image name and extension.  example "Julie.jpg".  How can I get the avatar to show as the full image?

I have also used the same to try **avatar_url**, but this show the file location:  https://my website.com/uploads/user/Julie.jpg